# How can I use my uPort account to migrate a solidity contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, metamask

I would like to use my uPort account to deploy a solidity contract. Is there a way to import my uPort account into metamask, or another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can actually do it with code. I'm still learning but with the the [`uport-connect`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uport-connect) module it might be something like this:

```
import { Connect } from 'uport-connect'
const uport = new Connect('example')
const address = await uport.requestAddress()
await uport.deploy(contract)
```

Here is another [example](https://github.com/uport-project/uport-js-client/blob/b8b46ffd004acc8a1e526f747a21ac89034185ab/examples/clientExample.js) which looks relevant.